# Reformatting memory sticks

Tags: usb-drive

I am giving a workshop in early April. I would like to give each participant a memory stick with the PowerPoint slides and some freeware software relative to the topic of the workshop. I was given a large quantity of memory sticks to "recycle" (I'm on a strict budget--everything comes out of my own pocket) that have an obsolete version of the DigSafe manual. The partition containing the document shows as a CD drive when I insert one into a computer.

How can I reformat these devices to remove the "CD" partition? I did find an old thread suggesting using dd and fdisk to format this type of device. Will that work in my case?

(It's not the end of the world if I can't -- my poor audience will just have to suffer with receiving the requirements of Dig Safe. Hi Hi).

Answer (score 1):

I would use **GParted** for this, **but be careful** so you don't click on the wrong drive and format and erase the wrong drive, such as your Ubuntu installation, or some other drive with a bunch of valuable data.  You might want to disconnect any extra drives from your system before you do this.

You can install **GParted** by typing this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install gparted
```